# Rails 4 - Using Moz API to display information in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using seomoz's [linkscape-gem](https://github.com/seomoz/linkscape-gem) to get data using their api, which I'd like in turn to display in a view. (note: I am also using the Wicked gem to build the object in steps). Currently I have this in my controller:

```
def update
  @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
  @linkscape = moz if step == steps.second
  @bid.attributes = build_params
  render_wizard @bid
end

def moz
  @client = Linkscape::Client.new(:accessID => "accessID", :secret => "secret")
  @response = client.urlMetrics("http://example.com", :cols => :all)
  return @response
end
```

and in my view:

```
<%= debug(@linkscape) %>
```

Nothing shows up in the debug portion of the view, so I am wondering if 1) I am using incorrect syntax 2) incorrectly accessing API info (I did create a Moz account and generate an access id and secret key, and they are being used) 3) misunderstanding how to display controller vars in views or 4) something else.

Comment: you should be reading this http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: @phoet Thanks for the link. There are some good practices and tools in there, but nothing that sticks out as being able to answer my question. I'm not running into any errors or problems when I check logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo: You are saving the `Linkspace::Client.new` instance inside an instance variable `@client` but you are trying to call `urlMetrics` on a variable named `client`, which it has no idea about.

```
def moz
  client = Linkscape::Client.new(:accessID => "accessID", :secret => "secret")
  @response = client.urlMetrics("http://example.com", :cols => :all)
  return @response
end
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the logger working and getting a response, you will have to correct the typo error first which is @response assigning should be changed to @client instead of client.

```
def moz
  @client = Linkscape::Client.new(:accessID => "accessID", :secret => "secret")
  @response = @client.urlMetrics("http://example.com", :cols => :all)
  return @response
end
```

Then in the view you could print he values using two way. First is using

```
Rails.logger.debug("My object: #{@linkscape.inspect}")
```

and view the development log to view the results

OR using your own way

```
<%= debug(" Linkscape Value"+@linkscape) %>
```

If your value is coming empty then it means the if condition is set to false and your @linkscape is not getting the values